# Regex pattern using w.* not matching text starting with foreign characters such as Ä

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have the following regex that I have been using successfully:

```
preg_match_all('/(\d+)\n(\w.*)\n(\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{2})\n(\d.*)\n(\d.*)/', $text, $matches)
```

However I have just found that if the text that the `(\w.*)` part matches starts with a foreign character such as `Ä`, then it doesn't match anything.

Can anyone help me with what the correct pattern should be instead of `(\w.*)` to match a string that starts with any character?

Many thanks

Comment: Thanks, just tried your code - no, it doesn't work

Comment: Did you just made shure you don't have a encoding issue? You could also try the hexadecimal value of these umlauts. Hint: utf8_encode()

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you *do* want to match umlauts, then add the regex `/u` modifier, or use `\pL` in place of `\w`. That will allow the regex to match letters outside of the ASCII range.

Reference: http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html
and http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php

Comment: Excellent - using `\pL` in place of `\w` works perfectly! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Ä is a German Umlaut if I am not mistaken. `\w` Matches (in most flavors) `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

You will need to match the unicode range of characters that you want.

`\x{00C4}` (php) equals the character you want. You will probably need to create a character class to support your unicode characters.

Answer (score 0):

you may have to switch to using unicode chars...

like for ascii you would use [\u0021-\u007e]  In this case... the maybe [\u0021-\u007e\u0192-\u687]

I'm not quite sure on what range of characters you want but the \w I think only match things in the normal asci range

Comment: The \u syntax is not supported in php, instead it is `\x{0021}-\x{007e}\x{0192}-\x{687}`

Answer (score 0):

Consider using:

```
/(\d+)\n((\p{L}|\p{N}|_).*)\n(\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{2})\n(\d.*)\n(\d.*)/
```