# Regexp for firstname and lastname

Tags: regex

I would like to find a regular expresson for validating user input for FirstName and LastName. Is there som kind of standard for this? I would like to avoid strange signs, yet allow international signs like `åäö`, etc.

I am using .NET

Any recommendations?

Comment: What language? Different language regexes have different built-in character classes

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8137467/898423 for the international signs problem.

Comment: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex for names with special characters (Unicode)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963228/regex-for-names-with-special-characters-unicode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is no single simple aswers. Closing this topic.

Answer (score -1):

This is not so easy to do.

One way to do it is like this:

```
[a-zA-Zåäö] etc.
```

Just add all the special characters needed to the list of allowed characters, but it's not how you **should** do it.

Instead, check this question on why this is a really difficult problem to solve:

[What are all of the allowable characters for people's names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421046/what-are-all-of-the-allowable-characters-for-peoples-names)

Comment: Feels like I opened Pandoras box here.....  but so far " What are all of the allowable characters for people's names?" are most to my likening....   Folowing the adwise in that question I should only have  one name field and allow any printable unicode character. IS THERE a definition for printable unicode charachters???

Comment: Don't even attempt to do it this way.

Comment: Yes, don't do it this way. It is a world of pain. See the link in my answer instead.

Comment: I followed your link emh,,,  and the conclusion on that thread are,, as I interpreted it, use one name field,, and allow "all printable" characters.  Am I misunderstanding something here guys?
(btw,, many links was broken in "What are all of the allowable characters for people's names?")

Comment: Yes, that is pretty much it. There is a good answer that reads "If you absolutely must check the validity of someone's name, I'd suggest doing a modest blacklist of certain characters. Braces, mathematical characters, some punctuation and such might be safe to ignore. But I'd be cautious, if I were you."